# Google Sheet - Collect each unique URL in a column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I'm a bit new to Google Apps script and also to javascript. I'm working on a function that generates a query to insert in the sheet, collecting all the unique URLs in a column and pairing them with a sheet name in another column.

Here the function is called and passed as parameters 3 columns. Column U contains the URLs of another spreadsheet, column W contains the name of the sheet inside the spreadsheet that I want to target with the query.

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sheetImport = ss.getSheetByName('Import');
sheetImport
    .getRange(2, 1)
    .setFormula(getFormulaImport_(sheet.getRange('U2:W').getValues()));
```

Here's the function as currently defined:

```
function getFormulaImport_(data){ 
  let formulaStart = '=IFERROR(QUERY({' 
  let formulas = [];
  let formulaEnd = '},"SELECT * WHERE Col5 is not null",FALSE),UPPER("No data found"))'
  
  let obj = {};  
  data.forEach(row => {obj[row[2]] = row[0];});
  
  for(let sheetName in obj){
    let urlE = obj[sheetName];
    if(urlE && sheetName) formulas.push(`IMPORTRANGE("${urlE}","'${sheetName}'!A3:X")`);
  }
  
  return formulaStart + formulas.join(';') + formulaEnd;
}
```

The function works perfectly if I have different sheet names connected to different URLs. But if I have the same sheet name linked to various URLs, it only includes the first URL in the query.

I'd like the function to recognize that if there's the same sheet name but a different URL, it should be also included in the formula.

How can I make it work? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you share and table of data and to go along with your [mcve].  By the way I don't follow link to other users accounts

Comment: It's not a good idea to use ranges like this is google apps script `'U2:W'` because they result in a lot of nulls in the sheet from `sheet.getLastRow() to sheet.getMaxRows();` which just have to be filtered out.

Comment: @Cooper I'm not sure I can I share with you a table of data without a link. Imagine a table where column A to T contain random data, U contains a link to another spreadsheet (for example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13-7jmywLseIQ1ch0SQEvUjWJxnv74egZtJQJLKoZAop/edit), column V contains a checkbox (which we don't consider in this function), column W contains the name of the sheet that I want to target in the previously linked spreadsheet (let's call it "TestSheet").
This for several rows of course, with various links in column U and various sheetnames in column W

Comment: You can use this code to copy it from your spreadsheet and redact private stuff: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/table-utility

Comment: It's also available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getFormulaImport() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let data = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  let formulaStart = '=IFERROR(QUERY({'
  let formulas = [];
  let formulaEnd = '},"SELECT * WHERE Col5 is not null",FALSE),UPPER("No data found"))'

  let obj = { pA: [] };

  data.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(r[2])) {
      obj[r[2]] = [];
      obj[r[2]].push(r[0]);
      obj.pA.push(r[2]);
    } else {
      obj[r[2]].push(r[0])
    }
  });

  obj.pA.forEach((s, i) => {
    obj[s].forEach((u, j)=>{
      formulas.push(`IMPORTRANGE("${u}","'${s}'!A3:X")`);
    });
  });
  Logger.log( formulaStart + formulas.join(';') + formulaEnd);
}
```

My Data in Sheet1:

| URL |  | SheetName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| url1 |  | name1 |
| url2 |  | name2 |
| url3 |  | name3 |
| url4 |  | name4 |
| url5 |  | name5 |
| url6 |  | name6 |
| url7 |  | name7 |
| url8 |  | name8 |
| url9 |  | name9 |
| url10 |  | name1 |
| url11 |  | name2 |
| url12 |  | name3 |
| url13 |  | name4 |
| url14 |  | name5 |
| url15 |  | name6 |
| url16 |  | name7 |
| url17 |  | name8 |
| url18 |  | name9 |
| url19 |  | name10 |

```
Execution log
6:12:58 PM  Notice  Execution started
6:12:59 PM  Info    =IFERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url1","'name1'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url10","'name1'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url2","'name2'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url11","'name2'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url3","'name3'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url12","'name3'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url4","'name4'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url13","'name4'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url5","'name5'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url14","'name5'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url6","'name6'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url15","'name6'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url7","'name7'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url16","'name7'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url8","'name8'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url17","'name8'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url9","'name9'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url18","'name9'!A3:X");IMPORTRANGE("url19","'name10'!A3:X")},"SELECT * WHERE Col5 is not null",FALSE),UPPER("No data found"))
6:12:59 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```