# How to speed up nested for loop in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a project that cross validate 2 sheets with approx 500 loops.

**ROSTER**

| First Name | Last Name | DoB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Judith | Barragan | 4/10/1959 |
| Kelly | Benitez | 9/14/1993 |
| Martha | Bustos | 1/12/1960 |
| Robyn | Carroll | 5/9/1954 |
| Janet | Chambers | 8/27/1949 |
| Nikki | Corso | 10/25/1957 |
| Angella | Decohen | 5/23/1988 |
| Damian | Delaney | 6/26/1961 |
| Anora | Denison | 4/14/1998 |
| Cristina | Dimatulac | 7/28/1959 |
| Mercy | Erazo | 3/14/1959 |
| Michelle | Fanara | 11/20/1981 |
| Shannon | Feldmann | 9/10/1986 |
| Alejandra | Frutos-Silva | 2/14/1978 |
| Rebecka | Aceves | 7/14/2007 |
| Jarely | Aguilera | 6/8/2006 |
| Jasmine | Aguillon | 1/29/2007 |
| Adriana | Alaniz | 10/4/2007 |
| Blanca | Angel | 11/3/2007 |
| Francie | Arellano | 9/11/2007 |
| Molly | Barajas | 10/1/2007 |
| Emily | Barranco | 9/12/2007 |
| Valeria | Bata | 3/29/2007 |
| Sarahi | Cabeza | 8/8/2007 |
| Carla | Cadena | 3/31/2006 |
| Emily | Cano | 1/25/2007 |
| Janet | Canul | 4/27/2007 |
| Caitlyn | Castaneda | 3/26/2007 |
| Jacqueline | Castillo | 1/22/2007 |
| Melanie | Colindres | 6/8/2007 |
| Nyah | Davis | 8/8/2007 |
| Karie | Delgadillo | 2/10/2007 |
| Gabriela | Diaz | 6/25/2007 |
| Helen | Diaz | 8/17/2007 |
| Hailey | Duran | 5/20/2007 |
| Hazel | Flores | 9/7/2007 |
| Kiherra | Gamboa | 10/4/2007 |
| Belen | Gonzalez | 4/23/2007 |
| Samantha | Gonzalez | 10/16/2007 |
| Ashlee | Palacios | 8/31/2006 |
| Naomi | Papaqui | 5/17/2007 |
| Karely | Paxtor | 10/21/2006 |
| Michelle | Paxtor | 10/20/2007 |
| Audra | Perez | 2/24/2007 |
| Josueline | Perez | 10/30/2006 |
| Yaretzi | Pineda | 2/17/2007 |
| Zuleyka | Portela | 9/10/2007 |
| Jacqueline | Prudencio | 3/1/2007 |
| Destiny | Quiroz | 5/10/2007 |
| Kelcey | Raiz | 5/11/2007 |
| Brianna | Ramos | 8/15/2007 |
| Neydy | Renderos | 8/26/2007 |
| Daiman | Johnson | 3/3/1968 |
| Kimberley | Rivas | 11/2/2007 |
| Michelle | Dominguez | 5/15/2005 |
| Marleny | Rodriguez | 7/29/2007 |
| Maria | Roman | 5/9/2006 |
| Cristal | Solis | 9/29/2006 |
| Carmela | Torralba | 6/28/2007 |
| Dora | Vasquez | 5/14/2007 |
| Cindy | Vega | 11/20/2007 |
| Jennifer | Velasco | 6/30/2006 |
| Chloe | Wilson | 10/8/2007 |
| Melody | Zacarias | 5/17/2007 |
| Hazel | Zamora | 1/27/2007 |
| Kayden | Alexander | 2/6/2006 |
| Yvette | Alvarado | 3/30/2006 |
| Damian | Delaney | 6/26/1961 |
| Kimberly | Amezcua | 7/14/2006 |
| Kimberly | Antonio | 5/30/2006 |
| Alicia | Aquino | 6/15/2006 |
| Samantha | Aquino | 6/27/2006 |
| Destiny | Arauz | 6/13/2006 |
| Julissa | Arroyo | 5/26/2006 |
| Cassandra | Ayala | 8/18/2006 |
| Samantha | Ayala | 7/2/2006 |
| Eva | Azul | 2/6/2006 |
| Stacey | Bacelis | 4/4/2006 |
| America | Baires | 7/17/2006 |
| Ashley | Barajas | 6/10/2005 |
| Janet | Barrera | 10/14/2005 |
| Alisa | Benitez | 5/26/2006 |
| Sara | Bolanos-Mejia | 1/12/2006 |
| Ashley | Mendez | 6/22/2006 |
| Ana | Carvente | 7/12/2006 |
| Mia | Castellanos | 6/19/2006 |
| Rosalma | Cebreros | 3/3/2006 |
| Yosselin | Celis | 5/25/2005 |
| Jacqueline | Lucero | 9/2/1974 |
| Evelyn | Chamu | 1/30/2006 |
| Nataly | Chavez | 2/27/2006 |
| Juliana | Coeto | 10/4/2005 |
| Shesith | Covarrubias | 12/8/2005 |
| Ashley | Cruz | 7/20/2006 |
| Erin | Dakers | 8/2/2007 |
| Claudia | Lopez | 6/16/2007 |
| Cristina | Diaz | 10/13/2005 |
| Zoe | Dighero | 4/11/2006 |
| Kaylynn | Domingo | 10/4/2006 |
| Celeste | Dominguez | 6/1/2006 |
| Lizzy | Escobar | 12/14/2005 |
| Lilian | Escorza | 12/23/2005 |

**REGISTRATION**

| First Name | Last Name | DoB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jacqueline | Lucero | 9/2/1974 |
| Ashley | Mendez | 6/22/2006 |
| Hyobe | Namkoong | 6/19/2007 |
| Hetzabel | Sanchez | 4/13/2005 |
| cristal | solis | 9/29/2006 |
| Briseida | Lopez | 5/22/2005 |
| Daiman | Johnson | 3/3/1968 |
| Kayleen | Vasquez | 12/9/2003 |
| Ashley | Aguilar | 12/9/2003 |
| Damian | Delaney | 6/26/1961 |
| Michelle | Dominguez | 5/15/2005 |
| Martha | Bustos | 1/12/1960 |
| Jaqueline | Granadino | 9/6/2004 |
| jacqueline | granadino | 9/6/2004 |
| Jacqueline | granadino | 9/6/2004 |
| Maria | Gutierrez | 11/30/2006 |
| Claudia | Lopez | 6/16/2007 |
| Kelly | Benitez | 9/14/1993 |
| Kelly | Benitez | 9/14/1993 |

**RESULT**

| First Name | Last Name | DoB | Start Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jacqueline | Lucero | 9/2/1974 | 1980001 |
| Ashley | Mendez | 6/22/2006 | 1980002 |
| Cristal | Solis | 9/29/2006 | 1980003 |
| Daiman | Johnson | 3/3/1968 | 1980004 |
| Damian | Delaney | 6/26/1961 | 1980005 |
| Michelle | Dominguez | 5/15/2005 | 1980006 |
| Martha | Bustos | 1/12/1960 | 1980007 |
| Claudia | Lopez | 6/16/2007 | 1980008 |
| Kelly | Benitez | 9/14/1993 | 1980009 |

[Sample Data Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17dZhD1XCnt_oXbRvSC1guYdBAMGpiQDUWwIDwZ1FLcI/edit?usp=sharing)
my problem is that my script sometimes getting run-time timeout. I am seeing map function but I'm not sure if it's applicable for my current problem.

here are my sheets that is included in my script.
sheets are roster, form responses 1, reference, result.
roster and registration tab have common columns (First name, Last Name, Date of Birth)

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
var rosterTab = SS.getSheetByName('Roster')
var registrationTab = SS.getSheetByName('Responses 1')
var referenceTab = SS.getSheetByName('Reference')
var resultTab = SS.getSheetByName('Result') //this is where I posts all registered names that is on the roster tab.
var xLastRow = registrationTab.getLastRow();
var yLastRow = rosterTab.getLastRow();
var Data = [];
var codeStart = referenceTab.getRange('A1').getValue();
var rosterdata = rosterTab.getRange(1,1,300,3).getValues();
var registerdata = registrationTab.getRange(1,1,xLastRow,3).getValues();

for(var i = 0; i<yLastRow; i++(){
      for(var j = 0; j<xLastRow; j++(){
        if (rosterdata[i][0] === registerdata[j][0] && rosterdata[i][1] === registerdata[j][1] && rosterdata[i][2] === registerdata[j][2]){
              var rosterFname = registerdata[j][0];
              var rosterLname = registerdata[j][1];
              var rosterDoB = registerdata[j][2];
              var rosterCode = codeStart;
              Data.push([rosterFname,rosterLname,rosterDoB,rosterCode]);
              break;
              }
           }
        }
     resultTab.getRange(resultTab.getLastRow()+1,1,Data.length,Data[0].length).setValues(Data);
```

Is there another way on how to approach this matching without getting timed-out?

Comment: You are getting unexpected token errors on the for loop lines for the extra parenthesis at the end of your loop statement

Comment: `var xLastRow = registrationTab.getLastRow();
  var xLastRow = rosterTab.getLastRow();` defined twice

Comment: Hi @Cooper I made the table above for reference, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
function myfunky11() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rosterTab = ss.getSheetByName('Roster');
  const registrationTab = ss.getSheetByName('Responses 1');
  const referenceTab = ss.getSheetByName('Reference');
  let rsh = ss.getSheetByName('Result'); 
  var data = [];
  const codeStart = referenceTab.getRange('A1').getValue();
  const ros = rosterTab.getRange(2, 1, rosterTab.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getDisplayValues().map(r => r[0] + r[1] + r[2]);
  const reg = registrationTab.getRange(2, 1, registrationTab.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  reg.forEach(r => {
    let s = r[0].toString() + r[1].toString() + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(r[2]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yyyy");
    if (ros.indexOf(s)>-1) {
      r.push(codeStart);
      data.push(r)
    }
  });
  rsh.clear();
  rsh.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

This works now

Comment: Hi @Cooper , Here's a sample data, [Sample Data Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17dZhD1XCnt_oXbRvSC1guYdBAMGpiQDUWwIDwZ1FLcI/edit?usp=sharing)  i also added toLower(), to make sure user input matched the names in the roster.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow links to spreadsheets. If you wish to post it as a table that would be much better for me.

Comment: I tried creating table here, It's working properly in preview, but it's not working when I posted. sorry I'm super new to posting here.

Comment: Perhaps this code can help you to make datg tables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table