# going from wide to long with empty cells in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, unpivot, flatten, textjoin

I am trying to go from wide to long for two columns with blanks retaining information in the last two columns.

[image]

Please see [google sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fHrkBlfcDflHxJPcI_4IJqALg4jTl5o8uakLBQKu8g8/edit?usp=sharing) for example and intended effect:

Comment: I don't really understand your question: could you please clarify what you mean by "I am trying to go from wide to long".

Comment: See example-- expand the two columns person1 and person2 into one column retaining information in day and title. I can do =ARRAYFORMULA(split(FLATTEN(A2:B4&"!"&C2:C4&"!"&D2:D4),"!")) , but the missing information in row 2 and 4 provides trouble for the output

Comment: Use [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) to show your data structure. You can easily create a table using  [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772209/) or the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. If you use formula, the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells, while `A1:G1` acts as a header. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(A2:B5="",,A2:B5&"×"&C2:C5&"×"&D2:D5)), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
=IF(ERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(split(FLATTEN(A2:B4&"!"&C2:C4&"!"&D2:D4),"!"))) = "FALSE" ,ARRAYFORMULA(split(FLATTEN(A2:B4&"!"&C2:C4&"!"&D2:D4), "!")))," ")
```