# How to subtract one row from another and place the values into a third row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Fairly new to this - trying to write a script in Google Sheets to subtract values across two rows (row 4 minus row 3) and place those values into a third row (row 2) overwriting anything that is already there.

I am attempting to say B4 to D4 minus B3 to D3 must be placed into B2 to D2.

The script that I have tried is:

```
function getAchieved() {
ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
s=ss.getSheetByName('TARGETS');

var endVal=s.getRange(4,2,1,3).getValue()
var startVal=s.getRange(3,2,1,3).getValue()
var achievedVal=endVal-startVal
s.getRange(2,2,1,3) .setValue(achievedVal)
}
```

However, this calculates only the first value and inserts that value into all the cells across row 2.

Help appreciated in advance!

Comment: Use [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) to show your data structure. You can easily create a table using  [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772209/) or the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. If you use formula, the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells, while `A1:G1` acts as a header. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getAchieved() {
ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
s=ss.getSheetByName('TARGETS');

var endVal=s.getRange(4,2,1,3).getValues()[0];
var startVal=s.getRange(3,2,1,3).getValues()[0];
var achievedVal=endVal.map((v,i)=>v-startVal[i]);
s.getRange(2,2,1,3).setValues([achievedVal])
}
```

Reference:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)