# Google Sheets Transpose Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, unpivot

How can I convert the data in the red cell to the data in the green cell?

[image]

Comment: Use [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) to show your data structure. You can easily create a table using  [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772209/) or the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. If you use formula, the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells, while `A1:G1` acts as a header. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=query(arrayformula(split(flatten(A2:A3&"|"&B2:F3),"|")),"select * where Col2 is not null")
```

if you have an undifined number fo rows, try

```
=query(arrayformula(split(flatten(A2:A&"|"&B2:F),"|")),"select * where Col2 is not null")
```

but limit the rows of the sheet to prevent long calculation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TRANSPOSE` Function documented here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en

Sample Usage

`TRANSPOSE({1,2;3,4;5,6})`

`TRANSPOSE(A2:F9)`

Syntax

`TRANSPOSE(array_or_range)`

```
`array_or_range` - The array or range whose rows and columns will be swapped.
```