# Unable to take sum of qty of part number form another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
=INDEX(QUERY(Tracker!A:G,"select sum(G) where B=' & Summary!$A$3 & '",1),1,0)
```

I have two sheets in a spreadsheet. My requirement is to get sum of qty of part number form sheet **tracker** to **summary**. Condition is (B column in Tracker sheet is equal to A3 in summary sheet).

Note : Formula is in Summary Sheet

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Use [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) to show your data structure. You can easily create a table using  [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772209/) or the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. If you use formula, the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells, while `A1:G1` acts as a header. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: Please add a copy to your (or a duplicate) spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(Tracker!A:G, "select sum(G) where B = '"&Summary!$A$3&"' label sum(G)'' ",1)
```