# How to unpivot this data right using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got the code below, which is not plotting the values as it should.

The idea is to pivot it, in a way that for each date in row 4, we have the set of products, quantities and other information repeated so as to create a DB like table.

```
function salvarPrevProducao() {
  const srcSheetName = "Previsão Entreposto"; // This is the source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "DB"; // Please set the destination sheet name.


  // This is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
  };

  // 1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const lastRow = srcSheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(1);
  const [[, , , ...header1], header2, ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getRange("A4:M" + lastRow).getValues();

  Logger.log('Header1: ' + header1)
  Logger.log('Header2: ' + header2)

  // 2. Create an array for putting to the destination sheet.
  const values = header1.reduce((ar, h, i) => {
    srcValues.forEach(([a, b, c, ...dm]) => ar.push([h, a, b, c, dm[i] || 0, "", dm.pop(), h]));
    return ar;
  }, [["Data", "Tipo", "Cod", "Descrição", "Qtd", "Usuário", "TimeStamp", "Semana"]]);

  // 3. Put the array to the destination sheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Here's what the data looks like prior to processing:

[image]

Here's how it should look as the result:
[image]

Here's the link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13WmD19BkkM-lpvMhu06SbfkPF-KSdmU9ZltAKc2mxmc/edit#gid=240927939

It's doing it right until the column where we have a date informed. For Usuário and Timestamp, it apparently repeats it all at the bottom and these 2 columns don't come in the first chunck of data.

Appreciate any help, as I can't even find where to begin.

Regards

Comment: I don't follow links to google accounts because it often exposes our emails and it also can be difficult to remove links to shared drives. If you wish to share data a better approach is to share images of pertinent sheets and use tables to pass data. Here's a link to script for [creating data tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table) and there are other methods probably as well.

Comment: How do I reproduce the problem?

Comment: First, share your sheet as **public**. Second, try to log the result ``values`` array and compare to what you need. Third, try to implement the ``reduce`` statement into a simpler ``for`` loop and build the result array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, your code is displaying additional rows because your `header1` array has trailing empty values:

```
Info    Header1: Mon Dec 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time),Tue Dec 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time),Wed Dec 29 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time),Thu Dec 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time),Fri Dec 31 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time),Sat Jan 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time),Sun Jan 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time),,,
```

You have to filter them out and push the corresponding temporary array values to your result:

```
  // 2. Create an array for putting to the destination sheet.
  const newHeader1 = header1.filter(v => v != '');
  const values = newHeader1.reduce((ar, h, i) => {
    srcValues.forEach(([a, b, c, ...dm]) => ar.push([h, a, b, c, dm[i] || 0, dm[dm.length-3], h, dm.pop()]));
    return ar;
  }, [["Data", "Tipo", "Cod", "Descrição", "Qtd", "Usuário", "TimeStamp", "Semana"]]);
```

The first data row should look like this:

[image]

Comment: So complex for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm sure it's not fair to take your time for this, but would it be possible to ellaborate on this line for learning purposes here? ```srcValues.forEach(([a, b, c, ...dm]) => ar.push([h, a, b, c, dm[i] || 0, dm[dm.length-3], h, dm.pop()]))``` Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**FORMULAIC STRATEGY**

I believe this is more of an 'unpivot' than a pivot.

You want to get pivoted data into database form.

You can use the SPLIT(FLATTEN(... technique for this.  See the tab called MK.Help on your shared sheet which [will also live here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FZ4lf_Un111J9BzodGUfJ4YoiBDWW62W4TOl0jHEmw4/edit#gid=1202655997) permanently for future users.
There you will find this formula:
This technique was made possible by the FLATTEN function which as always been available, but was hidden from users and only discovered about 2 years ago.  It "flattens" 2d data into one dimension which is ideal for creating Database-like structures out of pivoted data.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN('Previsão Entreposto'!A6:A&"|"&'Previsão Entreposto'!B6:B&"|"&'Previsão Entreposto'!C6:C&"|"&'Previsão Entreposto'!D6:J&"|"&'Previsão Entreposto'!D5:J5&"|"&'Previsão Entreposto'!D4:J4&"|"&'Previsão Entreposto'!K6:K&"|"&'Previsão Entreposto'!L6:L&"|"&'Previsão Entreposto'!M6:M&"|"&FLOOR('Previsão Entreposto'!D4:J4-2;7)+2);"|";0;0);"select Col6,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col7,Col8,Col10 where Col4 is not null order by Col6,Col3";0))
```

**APPS SCRIPT STRATEGY**

Below is some fairly simple code that should accomplish the 'unpivoting' you're after.  The simplest way to do it (in my opinion) is to just loop through the inner/repeated columns as it's own for loop (done here with the variable j from 3 to 9), each iteration pushing out a new complete row to a 'finishedValues' variable.  You can find the code and test it in the same sample sheet as mentioned above.  The output goes to the DB (Script) tab.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  const dbSheet = ss.getSheetByName('DB (Script)');
  const values = dataSheet.getRange('A6:M').getValues().filter(e=>e[0]);
  const dates = dataSheet.getRange('D4:J4').getValues()[0];
  var finishedValues = [];

  for(let i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    for (let j=3,row=values[i];j<10;j++){
      finishedValues.push([dates[j-3]].concat(row.slice(0,3)).concat(values[i][j]).concat(row.slice(10)))
    }
  }
  //Write the finished values to the lowest row on the DB (Script) tab.
  dbSheet.getRange(dbSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,finishedValues.length,finishedValues[0].length).setValues(finishedValues);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot! The challenge here consists of saving the data from one sheet to the other from time to time.

Comment: The idea is that you would have a simple script that would just paste those 'live' values from the MK.Help tab into the bottom of the DB tab whenever you wanted.

Comment: I'll resort to that, if I can't move forward like this. I am using it to study, as well. Thanks.

Comment: @AntonioSantos I've updated my answer (and the sample sheet) with a fairly simple script that seems to work fine.