# Google Sheets Script to copy rows duplicates the rows several times

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently using this script to move (selected) rows from one google sheet into another using checkbox.
It moves the rows fine but the move keeps duplicating if I do not physically go back and uncheck each row.
1)Am I using the correct script to copy the selected data?
2)and if so what can be done to prevent duplicates?
3)How do i make the checkbox to be a part of the code as well?
Thanks for whatever help I can get.

```
function moveChecked(){
const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const ss = sh.getSheetByName("Original Data Sheet");
const outSheet = sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

let data = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,48).getValues();
let out = [];
for (let i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
if (data[i][0] == true){
out.push(data[i]);
         }
}
outSheet.getRange(outSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,out.length,48).setValues(out);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### Move Checked

```
function moveChecked() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 48).getValues();
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let out = [];
  //let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[0] == true) {
      out.push(r);
      //sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++)
    }
  });
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, out.length, out[0].length).setValues(out)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However this deletes the row from the original sheet. All data must remain in the original sheet as it gets automatically updating from another service

Comment: Easily fixed....

Comment: now its pulling only one row from row 2400.

Comment: I also found this script from another post which seem to be using a column (Date) to match new data and update. my unique column is (SKU). Other issue also, is that it pushes all rows instead of seleccted rows.   See that script below

Comment: function copyRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var srg=ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow()+1,ssh.getLastColumn());//assume 1 header row
  var svs=srg.getValues();
  var trg=tsh.getRange(2,1,tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);//assume 1 header row
  var tvs=trg.getValues().map(function(r){return new Date(r[0]).valueOf();});
  svs.forEach(function(r,i){

Comment: //if it is not in the target then append it to the target
    if(tvs.indexOf(new Date(r[0]).valueOf())==-1) {
      tsh.appendRow(r);
    }
  });
}

Comment: You're going to have to share some of your data with me in a table so that I can copy and paste it because I tested this before I posted it and it's working for me.

Comment: here is the one with your code https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS9wFNRzB1dtkFiutDAGQXXs_HoQ6S9z_93dzQYp60lvZFCKttHeQWWKwzwSxIoYkd0gkza4TIr-vcb/pub?output=csv

Comment: this one with other script   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSCP_DyWTgZjhcnHalBZH5RJ4yrmI7GE7piAH9d4f1ywzbZtzc3Lrj6cKzgS-z7YXNkjpni71rPc9q6/pub?output=csv

Comment: So much appreciate your time as well

Comment: I'd prefer posting the data into a table and post it in your question.

Comment: Sorry I you lost me :)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table

Comment: |SKU| Localized For| Title| Product Description| Picture URL 1| UPC| MPN| Brand|