# google sheets apply funcation with spacing between

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm working on a google sheets project the target is to collect some information from google form and do some data manipulation to it and hand it to the clint.

I wanna way to apply funcation with spacing between .
For more clarification let's say I have a colum named A that contanins data like the following

A

row 1->10

row 2->empty

row 3->empty

row 4->12

row 5->empty

row 6->empty

row 8->11

row 9->empty

row 10->empty

row 11->25

row 12->empty

row 13->empty

so I wann my function => F(the-value-of-the-above-row) to be applied in row 2 and take row 1 as input and row 5 and take row 4 as input etc. for row 9 and 12

I hope It's clear , If you are reading this Thanks for you time, And If you answered the qusetion. Thnx. in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts for helpful posts from this site as is suggested  in [ask].

Comment: It's not clear to me.  Please provide a table of input and require outputs

Comment: If you want to try a way to make tables directly from spreadsheets try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table

Comment: please format your question for improved readability

Answer (score 0):

Use the [arrayformula(vlookup(row()))](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/154715/269219) pattern to fill *another* column with values based on the data you have in column `A`. Then refer to the new column in your script code or formulas down the road.