# How can I get and set cells values based on 2 criteria and 1st is date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm struggling with my project. I can't get cell values, please if somebody help me with that.

In my project I have Roster tab and Holiday request tab, I want to find in roster tab cells that are in between dates from the Holiday request tab for that particular name and setValue("Holiday").

I tried with for loop, and didn't have any success, and map and get the indexOf column and find and no success to get it.

Here's the code I have

```
function Holidays() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Holiday request from
  var master = ss.getSheetByName("Holiday Request");
  //Roster tab
  var target = ss.getSheetByName("Roster");
  // 
  var values = target.getRange("A3:NI20").getValues();
  var lc = target.getRange(3, 1, 1,target.getLastColumn()-1).getValues();

  //
  var appdis = master.getRange("G2:G250").getValues();
  var name = master.getRange(2,3, master.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var sdate = master.getRange(2,4, master.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var edate = master.getRange(2,5, master.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

  sdate.map(d =>{
    d[0]
    var shd = sdate.find(n => n[0] == d[0])
      
      name.map(n =>{
        n[0]
        var sname = values.find(r => r[0] == n[0])
      
      for(i=0, j=0; i<values.lenght, j<values[i].lenght; i++, j++){
        if(i == sname && j == shd)
          var cells = values.getRange(i, j).getValues();
          cells.setValues("Holiday");
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Here is the file

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i3qMZgls3_WRPY5QSlQJo802D7xYDO80dih8E2-Vrd4/edit#gid=399093041

Any help will be really appreciated!

UPDATE!!!

I did research as I was advised. Now I am able to extract value for just one date from the list, as well I transformed the sname 2d array into Object. The difficult part is I still don't get it how to loop though the multiple dates that I have. With get.DisplayValue() it get one date, with get.DisplayValues() I can get all of them but can't get the indexOf all of them. Here's what I have

```
function Holidays() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Holiday request from
  var hsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Holiday Request");
  //Roster tab
  var target = ss.getSheetByName("Roster");
  // Roster values
  //var dates = target.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var rosvalues = target.getRange(1, 1, target.getLastRow()-1,target.getLastColumn()-1).getValues();
  var [, , dates, , ...rvalues] = target.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  var sdate = hsheet.getRange(3, 4, hsheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getDisplayValue();
  //for(i=0; i<sdate.length; i++){
    var col = dates.indexOf(sdate);
    Logger.log(col)
  //}
  
  
  var sname = hsheet.getRange(2, 3, hsheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  
  Logger.log(sdate)
  Logger.log(sname)

  var fcol = rvalues.reduce((o, r) => {
    if(r[0]) o[r[0]] = r[col];
    return o;
  }, {});

  Logger.log(fcol)

  var nameObj = sname.reduce((a, [val1, val2]) => {
    a[val1] = val2;
    return a;
  },{});

Logger.log(nameObj)
  
  var textObj = { "08 - 17": "Holiday", "17 - 02": "Holiday", "11 - 20": "Holiday"};
  var key1 = Object.keys(textObj);
  var key2 = Object.keys(nameObj);
  var cell = rosvalues.map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => fcol[c] && key1.includes(fcol[c]) && key2.includes(fcol[c]) ? textObj[fcol[c]] : null));

  cell.setValue("Holiday");
  Logger.log(cell)
}
```

Please if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Loop not working is not a question.

Comment: @Cooper Can you please help me with it?

Comment: You cannot ask if one Date() object equals another Date() object. You should review [Javascript dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: @Cooper Can you please give me an idea how to do it?

Comment: I already have.  Do some research.

Comment: @Cooper hello, do you have any suggestion, please?

Comment: I did an example for you below which calculate workdays during the request period

Answer (score 1):

This function will calculate the total number of work days during the period of the holiday request and place that number in column 6 of the request sheet for each person on the list.  I presumed that works days are days that do not contain the string "OFF"

```
function Holidays() {
  const mA = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const req = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//request sheet
  const reqvs = req.getRange(2, 1, req.getLastRow() - 1, req.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const ros = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//roster sheet
  const rosdates = ros.getRange(3, 8, 1, ros.getLastColumn() - 7).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const rosnames = ros.getRange(5, 1, ros.getLastRow() - 4).getDisplayValues().flat();
  let vs;//I put vs up here so that I could see it in the debugger
  reqvs.forEach(([, , n, s, e, d, ,], i) => {
    let name = n;
    let idx = rosnames.indexOf(name);
    if (~idx) {
      wds = 0;
      let row = idx + 5;
      let sd = new Date(s);//start date
      let ed = new Date(e);//end date
      const ds = dateStrings(sd, ed);
      vs = rosdates.map((d, j) => { if (~ds.indexOf(d)) { return j + 8; } else { return ''; } }).filter(e => e);//returns column numbers and they are always consecutive
      ros.getRange(row, vs[0], 1, vs.length).getValues().flat().forEach(v => { if (v != "OFF") { wds += 1; } });
      req.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue(wds)
    }
  });
}

function dateStrings(Day1,Day2) {
  const mA = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  if(Day1 && Day2 && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day1) === '[object Date]') && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day2) === '[object Date]')) {
    var day=86400000;
    var t1=new Date(Day1).valueOf();
    var t2=new Date(Day2).valueOf();
    var d=Math.abs(t2-t1);
    var days=Math.floor(d/day); 
    let dA = Array.from(new Array(days + 1).keys(),x => {
      let dt = new Date(Day1.getFullYear(),Day1.getMonth(),Day1.getDate() + x);
      return `${dt.getDate()} ${mA[dt.getMonth()]}`;
    });
    //Logger.log(dA);
    return dA;
  } 
}
```

The Roster Sample Sheet:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 21 | 23 | 25 | 27 | 29 | 31 | 33 | 35 | 37 | 39 |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Sat | Mon | Wed | Fri | Sun | Tue | Thu | Sat | Mon | Wed |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 Jan | 2 Jan | 3 Jan | 4 Jan | 5 Jan | 6 Jan | 7 Jan | 8 Jan | 9 Jan | 10 Jan | 11 Jan | 12 Jan | 13 Jan | 14 Jan | 15 Jan | 16 Jan | 17 Jan | 18 Jan | 19 Jan | 21 Jan | 23 Jan | 25 Jan | 27 Jan | 29 Jan | 31 Jan | 2 Feb | 4 Feb | 6 Feb | 8 Feb |
| 4 | Name | TL | Lang | EID | LI ID | Leaver |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | Name 1 | Name 1 |  |  |  |  |  | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | OFF | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | OFF | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | OFF | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | OFF | 17 - 02 |
| 6 | Name 2 | Name 2 |  |  |  |  |  | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 |
| 7 | Name 3 | Name 3 |  |  |  |  |  | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 |
| 8 | Name 4 | Name 4 |  |  |  |  |  | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 |
| 9 | Name 5 | Name 5 |  |  |  |  |  | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 |
| 10 | Name 6 | Name 6 |  |  |  |  |  | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 |
| 11 | Name 7 | Name 7 |  |  |  |  |  | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF |
| 12 | Name 9 | Name 9 |  |  |  |  |  | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 |
| 13 | Name 10 | Name 10 |  |  |  |  |  | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 |
| 14 | Name 11 | Name 11 |  |  |  |  |  | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 |
| 15 | Name 12 | Name 12 |  |  |  |  |  | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 |
| 16 | Name 13 | Name 13 |  |  |  |  |  | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF |
| 17 | Name 14 | Name 14 |  |  |  |  |  | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | OFF | 17 - 02 | 17 - 02 |
| 18 | Name 15 | Name 15 |  |  |  |  |  | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 | OFF | 08 - 17 | 08 - 17 |

The Request Sample Sheet:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Request Date | Username | Name | Start Date | End Date | WorkDays | Approved | Reason |
| 2 | 30 Mar | ag1 | Name 1 | 1 Jan | 6 Jan | 4 |  |  |
| 3 | 31 Mar | ag2 | Name 2 | 16 Jan | 27 Jan | 10 |  |  |
| 4 | 31 Mar | ag3 | Name 3 | 10 Jan | 20 Jan | 8 |  |  |

- [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: thank you very much for your advice and help. I've learned something new since yesterday and now from your script. Thank you very much!