# Getting developer metadata set on a column (AppScript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help checking the metadata for a specific column. I have developer metadata set on each column of a sheet, what I'm trying to do is access the metadata individually for a column.

using:`sheet.getRange("A:A").createDeveloperMetadataFinder().withLocationType(SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataLocationType.COLUMN)`

works fine but is there a way i can achieve while passing integers in getRange and not letters?

Comment: You like this? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

Answer (score 0):

#### MetaData for a range

```
function displayMetaDataForARange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//change sheet name as required
  const rg = sh.getRange(1,column,sh.getLastRow());//change column as required
  var v = rg.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().onIntersectingLocations().find();
  let md = [];
  v.forEach(e => {
    let obj = {};
    obj['key'] = e.getKey();
    obj['value'] = e.getValue();
    obj['visibility'] = e.getVisibility();
    if (e.getKey().toString().slice(0, 3) == 'row') {
      obj['A1'] = e.getLocation().getRow().getA1Notation();
      let w = getRowWidth(e.getLocation().getRow().getRow(), sh, ss);
      obj['rowWidth'] = w;
      obj['rowvalues'] = e.getLocation().getRow().getValues().flat().filter((r, i) => i < w).join(',');
    } else {
      obj['A1'] = e.getLocation().getColumn().getA1Notation();
      let h = getColumnHeight(e.getLocation().getColumn().getColumn(), sh, ss);
      obj['colheight'] = h;
      obj['colvalues'] = e.getLocation().getColumn().getValues().flat().filter((c, i) => i < h).join(',');
    }
    obj['id'] = e.getId();
    md.push(obj);
    //e.remove();
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<textarea rows="25" cols="150">' + JSON.stringify(md) + '</textarea>').setWidth(1200).setHeight(600), 'Meta Data');
}- [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)