# Drop down list should be automated to copy and paste

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

Lets say I selected Funded in drop down list located in C2 than I would like the value of B2 copied to A2

There are numbers in the column UPCOMING INCOME and drop down list in the next column. When we choose in drop down Payed (PENDING, PAYED, PAUSED) it should copy the number from the Upcoming income column and paste to column FUNDED. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDz9Q.png)

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide your code and what you've attempted so far? That can help others provide you with a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I dont have a code yet. Was asking here if I could get help to write it

Comment: I see. Well, best practice is to attempt to solve it yourself first in app script before posting your question, and then ask for details from there when you get stumped. I will offer some advice on how I would solve it at the very least. Have a method that checks if 'on edit', the value in the status column has been changed to one of the values you mentioned, and if it is, then 'do something else'. That 'do something else' should paste the value from the 'upcoming income' column into the funded column.

Comment: You could do what you are asking with an onEdit function.  Please explain every detail about what you want the onEdit function to do.

Comment: So when I choose from a Drop Down list an option Funded it should copy the value from the cell and paste to another cell. I have attached the screeenshot of it

Comment: Lets say I selected Funded in drop down list located in C2 than I would like the value of B2 copied to A2

Comment: Please add your explanations to your question so that everyone will see them clearly without having to read all of the comments

Comment: Your explanation don't agree with your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should theoretically do what you're asking it to do, you just need to set a trigger for 'on edit' in the triggers tab when setting up your script.

```
function someFunction(){
  //Gets the spreadsheet with the name you specified
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet4')
  //Creates a 2D-Array of values based on the range you specify
  var dataRange = ss.getRange(2,6,ss.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues()
  //Runs through the 2D-array, checking every value for a match
  for(var i = 0; i < dataRange.length; i ++){
    for(var j = 0; j < dataRange[i].length; j++){
      //If there is a match, pastes the value from the 'Upcoming Income' column to the 'Funded' column
      dataRange[i][j] == 'Payed' ? ss.getRange('A'+(i+2)).setValue(dataRange[i][0]) : null
    }
  }
}
```

This is at least how I would solve it, but I'm sure there are many other quicker more elegant ways of doing so. You will have to make adjustment so that it will work with your spreadsheet, but I believe they should be fairly simple. If there is an error, please let me know, and I'll do my best to fix it.

In the future, please do what @Cooper recommended and make sure your question is more clear in what it is asking, and please attempt to code it yourself first before asking for help from others.

Comment: Thank you for your time. To be honest I dont know almost nothing in coding so I was just experimenting with automatation. How could I do that google sheets always runs this code and I dont need to press on run button every time to execute it?

Comment: Your dataRange has more lines in it than there is data

Comment: It is executing with some 2-3 sec delay. Is it possible to make it quick. Like a live responce

Comment: @TimKane you can attempt Cooper's method, however I am unaware of how to boost the time it takes to process. Remember, App Script is a free GOOGLE service (they have lots of servers, but people also pay to use them, so they get priority), which means there are going to be a lot more people using it, which limits server resources available, which in turn will cause processes to take a little longer. I am no expert on cloud computing, but as far as I know, no, there isn't a way to improve speed. Spreadsheet size might also be affecting the runtime of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Moving F to A

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.range.rowStart > 1 ) {
    e.range.offset(0,-7).setValue(e.range.offset(0,-2).getValue());
  }
}
```

- [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Will this get a value from drop down list?

Comment: It can.  What do you need?