# Trying to create a script that would send an email to multiple users on a spreadsheet, im a complete beginner to Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, function, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a function and add a trigger to send an email for every email address added on a spreadsheet, and I am facing a couple of difficulties.

This is the script so far:

```js
function sendEmail() {

// Fetch the email address

var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Incident name/scenario").getRange("R2:R100")
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();

// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'You have been mentioned on the spreadsheet.'; 

// R Column
var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
```

1. I want every time an email address is entered on column R for it to send an email to the mentioned person. So far it only works if I enter an email on R2, as I understood I need to create some sort of loop, however not sure how to approach this, as I don't want it to resend to every person on column R when a new email is entered.
2. If I tried to choose `getValues()` instead of `getValue()` I would get an error considering it works differently.
3. Is there a way to also restrict it to send emails that end with a specific way, and skip any emails that don't match without causing any errors, i.e. "@michael.com" , "@recreat.com" etc.

Comment: I'm afraid your work process is unclear.  Are you only adding 1 email at a time, or could it be multiple emails, copied from somewhere else? Are they at the end of a list or anywhere in the list?  You want some domains but not others?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please avoid including information about yourself (.i.e. I'm a beginner) in questions, you could add that in your user profile. Only use Stack Snippet for HTML/CSS/JavaScript that could be executed here (Google Apps Script methods can't be directly executed here). Questions on this site should be specific, meaning only one question/issue/problem/concern by post.

Comment: @TheWizEd email addresses added could be one or multiple, it is a shared spreadsheet that plenty of people contribute to. The aim of adding email addresses is to notify the person that he was mentioned in the spreadsheet. All of them are added in one single column, which is column R. Could be on any row, therefore the whole column. They could also be anywhere in column R, won't be added in order. I would like it also to avoid email addresses that are unrelated. All email addresses will have the same ending i.e. "gmail.com", so if it ends with "outlook.com" to just skip it. Duplicates are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that you a table of emails like this:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Emails |
| 2 | email1 |
| 3 | email2 |
| 4 | email3 |
| 5 | email4 |
| 6 | email5 |
| 7 | email6 |
| 8 | email7 |
| 9 | email8 |
| 10 | email9 |
| 11 | email10 |

All you have to do is

```
function getEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const emails = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().join(",");
  return emails;
}
```

Then in your email script:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(getEmails(),....
```

- [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)