# In Google Sheets, how to paste a series of cells in a row vertically and break and go to the next row and repeat the same process?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As you can see from the attached sheet, I need to evaluate cells B2:K5 in "Internal Split" and paste cells that have values into Column A of sheet "Accounting Split". When it finds an empy cell (example: Cell D2), it should break and start looking in the next row for cells with values until it pastes all values vertically in column A of "Accounting Split". Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain by example what you want accounting split to look like.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not much of a coder so I was able to achieve the desired result with formulas on Google Sheets

Here is the formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,'Internal Split'!C2:Q2,'Internal Split'!C3:Q3,'Internal Split'!C4:Q4,'Internal Split'!C5:Q5,'Internal Split'!C6:Q6),","))
```

What this formula does is first go through a range of cells and return cells with values separated with a comma. The output is in one cell. It then splits this cell into multiple values. Finally it transposes this result to display the results vertically. I hope that this is explained clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pivot() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Internal Split");
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange(2,1 , sh1.getLastRow() - 1, 11).getValues();
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Accounting Split");
  let o = vs1.map(r => {
    return r.slice(1).filter(e => e).map(e => [r[0],e])
  }).flat();
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o))
  o.unshift(["Country","Cost"]);
  sh2.clear();
  sh2.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Delivery | Cost 1 | Cost 2 | Cost 3 | Cost 4 | Cost 5 | Cost 6 | Cost 7 | Cost 8 | Cost 9 | Cost 10 |
| 2 | South Africa | 500 | 300 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | China | 400 | 200 | 700 | 800 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | USA | 100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | Brazil | 800 | 670 | 450 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Output:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Country | Cost |
| 2 | South Africa | 500 |
| 3 | South Africa | 300 |
| 4 | China | 400 |
| 5 | China | 200 |
| 6 | China | 700 |
| 7 | China | 800 |
| 8 | USA | 100 |
| 9 | Brazil | 800 |
| 10 | Brazil | 670 |
| 11 | Brazil | 450 |

- [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Could you take a look at the sheet again? I changed it a bit. Basically I need the identifier to be associated with the cost. Basically in the Accounting Split sheet, it should be:
Column A     ColumnB
1                    500
2                    300
3                    400
etc.

Comment: I dont understand what you want

Comment: Please provide examples and explain them