# How to copy rows from query sheet to destination and modify cell on source sheet based on unique ID column

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 3 sheets
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rTvInVG8hR06V2tPEmjqoDvSs_9-QrW08-oW6m-yHnk/edit#gid=1830441210

Source sheet /
Query sheet from source /
Destination sheet /

Can someone please help me with a function to copy rows from query sheet to destination sheet and after that to modify the column H in source sheet with text "yes" based on the unique id column G.

I've managed to do only this and don't know how the rest could be achieved.

```
function copyRows() { 
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const query_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('query');
  const target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Target');
  const source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  const startRow = 11; 
  var outdata = [];
  var numrows = 0;
  var lastRownum = query_sheet.getLastRow();

  if ('Last row = ' + lastRownum);

  if (lastRownum > 1) {
    outdata = query_sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRownum - startRow + 1, 9).getValues();
    numrows = outdata.length;
    pasteMultipleRows(target_sheet, outdata)
  }
  
  
  if  (numrows + ' Rows Inserted into Master'); 

}

function pasteMultipleRows(target_sheet, data) {
  var lastRow = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  if (data.length + ' rows will be written to ' + target_sheet + ' from ' + lastRow); 
  
  target_sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

[Source sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PvR1.png)

[image]

[query sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZuvF.png)

[image]

Data Table:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | title |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | title |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | title |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | title |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | title |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | title |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | title |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 |  | Id | Market | Value | Probability | Result Result | Details | UID | copied or not |
| 11 |  | 16082365 | sales | 14.02 | 61.07 | FALSE | table | 16082365sales |  |
| 12 |  | 16082367 | sales | 3.31 | 41.32 | TRUE | table | 16082367sales |  |
| 13 |  | 16082368 | sales | 17.55 | 40.86 | TRUE | table | 16082368sales |  |

after script run

[target sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhrwf.png)

[image]

and after that source sheet to look like this

[source sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb8qE.png)

[image]

Thank you

Comment: "I need" is not a question?

Comment: Sorry for "need"... The question is if someone can help me, please? Thank you

Comment: This site has rules posting rules that are very different from other places. Please read [ask]. Also checkout [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1595451)

Comment: Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: @Cooper I've updated the question with code and a spreadsheet example.

Comment: Does you code work?

Comment: @Cooper yes. But only the part of copying the rows. I don't know how to modify cells of copied rows (in the source sheet) based on unique ID column.

Comment: Can you provide a respresentative sample of data from your sheets in a table? [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)

Comment: @Cooper I added images on question... If I understood right...

Comment: Images can be informative but they don't allow us to copy and paste data so they limit our ability to assist you and I don't like to follow links to your spreadsheet because it exposes my email to you.  I created an application that makes creating markdown tables easy.  You should give it a try [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table) Even TheMaster recommends it

Comment: I posted a markdown table in your question using the script that I linked to.  No users can access your data to provide you with greater assistance.

Comment: |Id|Market|Value|Probability|Result Result|Details|UID|copied or not|
|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|
|16082365|sales|14.02|61.07|false|table|16082365sales|Redacted|
|16082367|sales|3.31|41.32|true|table|16082367sales||
|16082368|sales|17.55|40.86|true|table|16082368sales||
|16082365|marketing|22.51|23.69|false|tv|16082365marketing||
|16082366|marketing|6.52|54.27|false|tv|16082366marketing||
|16082368|marketing|150|38.19|false|tv|16082368marketing||

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work as well in comments as it does in questions or answers

Comment: And putting details about your question in comments isn't very useful because then othher users have to read all of the comments and they may not wish to invest their time in that effort.  So if you want their help you will want to make it as easy as possible for them.

Comment: When I try to edit and put the code it says: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function copyRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const qsh = ss.getSheetByName('query');
  const sr = 11;
  const vs = qsh.getRange(sr, 2, qsh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, qsh.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues();
  const ids = vs.map(r => r[6]).flat();
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Target');
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  const svs = ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow() - 1, ssh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map(r => {
    let idx = ids.indexOf(r[6])
    if(~idx) {
      r[7] = 'Yes';
    }
    return [r[7]];
  })
  ssh.getRange(2,8, svs.length,svs[0].length).setValues(svs);
}
```