# Is there a way to concatenate a column of data if 2 other columns equal each other?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to find a way to concatenate a column of data if 2 other columns equal each other using google apps scrip. I have a formula that does this: "ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" | ",True,IF($A$2:A=D2,$B$2:$B,"")))" but it is very slow when looking at large data sets.

Here is what I have right now.

```
function my_concat() {
  
var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1blPwXgg1DTJCTxmWikU5b0IZUgDxxQR13WbN7UI4_Yo");
var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName("TEST");
var range = sheetraw.getRange("B2:B");
var data = range.getValues();
var last = range.getLastRow();


for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++){
var range1 = sheetraw.getRange(i,1).getValue();
var range2 = sheetraw.getRange(i,4).getValues();
    
    if(range1 == range2){
    var data1 = (data[i] + " | " + data[i]);
    sheetraw.getRange('C' + 2 + ':C' + last).setValue(data1);


}
}
}
```

Here is a link to my g-sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1blPwXgg1DTJCTxmWikU5b0IZUgDxxQR13WbN7UI4_Yo/edit#gid=1418632603

When I ran the scrip I got looping information went line by line and concatenated what was in that line.

**What I got:** Chicken, Breast Strips - 10 Ounce (oz) | Chicken, Breast Strips - 10 Ounce (oz)

**What I am expecting:** Chicken, Breast Strips - 10 Ounce (oz) | Sauce, Ponzu - 6 Milliliter (ml) | Sauce, Sweet Thai Chili  - 1 Ounce (oz) | Garlic, Unpeeled - 1 Clove | Lime - 1 Piece (pc) | Peanut Butter - 1.15 Ounce (oz) | Cucumber, Persian - 1 Piece (pc) | Korean Chili Flakes - 1 Teaspoon (tsp) | Cilantro - 0.25 Ounce (oz) | Quinoa, White - 0.5 Cup (c) | Stock Concentrate, Chicken - 9.6 Gram (g)

Answer (score 0):

If A = D C = B | C

```
function my_concat() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("TEST");
  const data = sh.getRange("A2:D" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  let o = data.map((r, i) => {
    if (r[0] == r[3]) {
      r[2] = `${r[1]} | ${r[2]}`;//this doesn't work with table markdown
    }
    return [r[2]];
  })
  sh.getRange(2,3,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o)
}
```

Data Before:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| 2 | 8 | 18 | 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 17 | 18 | 8 | 17 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 10 | 13 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 18 | 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 15 | 18 |
| 8 | 5 | 12 | 4 | 10 |
| 9 | 2 | 12 | 16 | 10 |
| 10 | 2 | 17 | 3 | 17 |

After:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| 2 | 8 | 18 | 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 17 | 18 | 18 , 8 | 17 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | 0 , 6 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 10 | 10 , 13 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 18 | 18 , 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 15 | 18 |
| 8 | 5 | 12 | 4 | 10 |
| 9 | 2 | 12 | 16 | 10 |
| 10 | 2 | 17 | 3 | 17 |

I modified the code a bit to use commas so it would work with table markdown

Comment: Thank you for this code Cooper, this works great to concatenate 2 columns of data that are right next to each other, but this does not work to concatenate all values in a single column if all the values in another column are the same.

Comment: I didn't see the second requirement in your question perhaps you could explain in a little more detail with some images that show before and after. You could also use markdown tables to provide that information [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)