# How do I create a dependent dropdown list by referencing column values?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to coding and need guidance/assistance on how to complete this code.

I created a parent dropdown list titled "ingredients" in google sheets via the data validation tab. I am attempting to create a dependent drop down list titled "variants " that appears with two criteria:

1. ONLY when the selected value from the parent drop down list is appears more than once on a reference sheet.
2. IF the the value that contains duplicates is selected, I want the dependent drop down list to display all variants, found in a different column on the reference sheet, to appear in the dependent drop down list.

I tried to obtain a range that consisted only of the values in the drop down list. However they are  displayed in a column and I cannot index this column in order to log its numerical value and reference it to the parent name.

Here is my code and snapshots of my data
[image: Code]
[image: ActiveSheet]
[image: Referene Sheet]

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table) - [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) - [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) - [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)