# Add URLs to confluence page created using rest api

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, confluence-rest-api

I am creating a confluence page with a table from google sheets that contain a column that contains URLs and some text. I wanted that URL to be clickable on the confluence page. I have tried some HTML tags but nothing seems to work. It is currently using storage representation.

The confluence HTML code is :

```
<table><tr>
<th><?= col1?></th>
</tr>

<? tabledata.forEach((r,a) =>{?>
<tr style="background-color:<?= tablebackdata[a][0] ?>"><td><?= r[0]?></td></tr><?})?>
</table>
```

The gs script -

```
function confluenceCreate () {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Please enter parent page link");
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  if (button === ui.Button.OK) {
      var pageurl = result.getResponseText()
      var TOKEN =  "dummy"
      var BASE_URL = "dummy"
      var SPACEKEY =  "dummy"
      var authHeader = 'Bearer ' + TOKEN
      var params = {
      'method' : 'get',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'headers' : {Authorization: authHeader},
      "muteHttpExceptions": false,
      "contentType": "application/json"
      }
      var surl = '/rest/api/content/?title='
      var eurl = '&spaceKey=GDT&expand=history'
      var purl = pageurl.split('/')
      var pname = purl [5]
      var full_link =  surl.concat(pname,eurl)
      var url1 = BASE_URL + full_link
      var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, params);
      var page = JSON.parse(response1).results;
      var pageid = page[0].id
      const header = ss.getRange(1,1,1,1).getValues()
      const col1 = header[0][0]
      var lr = ss.getLastRow()
      var tabledata = ss.getRange(2,1,lr,1).getValues();
      var tablebackdata = ss.getRange(2,1,lr,23).getBackgrounds();
      const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("confluence");
        htmlTemplate.col1 = col1;
        htmlTemplate.tabledata = tabledata;
        htmlTemplate.tablebackdata = tablebackdata;
        c = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
        var pagename = 'Test'
        var full_name =  pagename.concat(" ","criteria")
        var TOKEN = "dummy"
        var BASE_URL = "dummy"
        var SPACEKEY = "dummy"
        var authHeader = 'Bearer ' + TOKEN
        var data = {
        'type': 'page',
        'title': full_name,
        "ancestors":[{"id":pageid}],
        'space': {'key': SPACEKEY},
        'body': {'storage':{'value': c, 'representation': 'storage'}}}
         var options = {
        'method' : 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'headers' : {Authorization: authHeader},
        'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)}
        var url = BASE_URL + '/rest/api/content'
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    }
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] that focuses on and highlights the url issue

Comment: Where's the rest of the html page?

Comment: Can you provide a [markdown table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table) for activeSheet()