# Same variable with unexpected multiple values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have no idea why this is happening, but it looks like a variable has two values, one correct and one unexpected value. When I print a variable in the console log, it shows at first the correct variable and right after it prints again another unexpected value. Is it a bug in AppScript, or something off that I cannot see?

Some extract of the code:

```
function funx(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxx');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
    var list = sheet.getRange(3,5,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getRichTextValues();
    var additionalList = sheet.getRange(3,3,sheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues(); //need another list  because rich text value does not get numbers

for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
  let datex = new Date(additionalList[i][0]);
Logger.log(datex); // this prints only one value and this is the correct value
  let date = getFDate(datex)}

}

function getFDate(rowDate){

  Logger.log(rowDate); // this prints two values. The first one is same as datex. The second one looks like a previous date which run when I called this function in the previous loop iteration.
  var year = rowDate.getFullYear();
  var month = (1 + rowDate.getMonth()).toString();
  month = month.length >1 ? month : '0' + month;
  var day = rowDate.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;

  var dateReturn = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
  return dateReturn;

}
```

The Logger.log prints two values!

5:58:48 PM  Info    Wed Nov 30 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2022 -> result of Logger.log(datex). This is the expected value

5:58:48 PM  Info    Wed Nov 30 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2022 -> result of Logger.log(rowDate). This is the expected value

5:58:48 PM  Info    2022-11-08T22:14:48.343+0000 -> result of Logger.log(rowDate). This is unexpected.

I purposely changed the name of the variable "datex" to make sure it is nowhere else in the code.

***_____ REASON OF ISSUE:***

**In another function as part of an IF statement that was never met, there was a Logger.log(getFDate(...)). I thought it was completely unrelated. But removing that fixed the issue. Looks like calling that function in a Logger.log caused its malfunction.**

Comment: If `The Logger.log prints two values!` is from `Logger.log(rowDate);`, the values of `list` are shown. In your situation, the values of `list` are not your expected values? For example, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample values of `list` and the sample output values you expect?

Comment: I updated the code above because actually the list I am using is not the list I am looping into due to the RichTextValue limitations in Google App scripts. However, I still cannot explain it. The first Logger log output the correct date in the additionalList. But it unexpectedly throw another value just after that. The values in additionalList[i][0] are dates in gSheet

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your script. Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual Spreadsheet, from your updated script, in your for loop, the values of `additionalList` retrieved by `getValues()` are used and each value of `additionalList` is shown in the log. In this case, if `The Logger.log prints two values!` is not your expected value, it is required to check the values of cells "C3:C". Can you confirm whether the values of cells "C3:C" are your expected values? For example, your expected column is "D3:D"?

Comment: Yes I confirm. In fact if I just print "datex" it just shows one value and it is correct. As soon as I call the getFDate function, the issue begins. This happens in my second iteration of the loop with i = 1 and the second value that it prints unexpectedly looks like a date I got in the previous loop run when i was = 0. I am thinking it is a google app bug and I am going to try to start a new google app project

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `In fact if I just print "datex" it just shows one value and it is correct.`, in your situation, I understood that you wanted to retrieve the values from column "C". If my understanding is correct, in order to confirm `This happens in my second iteration of the loop with i = 1 and the second value that it prints unexpectedly looks like a date I got in the previous loop run when i was = 0`, I think that it is required to confirm the values of your Spreadsheet.

Comment: About `I am going to try to start a new google app project`, in this case, how about creating a new Google Spreadsheet and testing it again?

Comment: starting a new project did not help. Still same issue. I believe "rowDate" is somehow corrupted. Seems "RowDate" holds a previous value when I called the function from the previous iteration. What could cause the "rowDate" to get corrupted? I updated the code above to include the results of my logs

Comment: About `starting a new project did not help.`, in your Spreadsheet, in your situation, are there multiple Google Apps Script projects? If it's so, for example, in your Google Apps Script projects, the functions of the same function names of `funx` and `getFDate` are existing? If the functions of the same function names are existing, the script might not correctly run. Please be careful about this. In that case, please create a new Spreadsheet and please open the script editor, and then, copy and paste your script and test it again.

Comment: Yes that is why I renamed from getDate() to getFDate(). Anyway I found the issue. Sorry I did not write the line of code who was causing it because I had no idea it was related to it. Basically there was a Logger.log(getFDate(...)) in one of my lines of code. It was part of an IF statement which I thought was totally unrelated. I removed it and now it works. Seems having the getFDate() as part of a Logger.log caused a mulfunction. Thank you so much for your answers and expertise

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: I would like to propose posting `REASON OF ISSUE:` as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_____ REASON OF ISSUE:

In another function as part of an IF statement that was never met, there was a Logger.log(getFDate(...)). I thought it was completely unrelated. But removing that fixed the issue. Looks like calling that function in a Logger.log caused its malfunction.

Extraction of that logger.log (it is part of a function which call Jira API and do something if some conditions are met)

```
Logger.log("DETECTED A CHANGE. Due Date changed by someone else: "+data["issues"][0].changelog["histories"][id].displayName+" on date: "+getFDate(data["issues"][0].changelog["histories"][id].created));
```

Comment: You will be able to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function funx() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxx');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var list = sheet.getRange(3, 5, sheet.getLastRow() - 2).getValues();// third parameter is the number of rows in the range not the last row in the range
  var additionalList = sheet.getRange(3, 3, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, 2).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    let datex = new Date(additionalList[i][0]);
    let date = getFDate(datex)
  }
}
```

I cannot reproduce your results because I do not have your data but several of your ranges were incorrect and getRichTextValues only return richTextValues and my guess is that you did not have any.  Please provide a data table if you wish more assistance.

[creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)

Comment: Thanks, I added the -2 but it still fails, the issue is not there. I have to use richtextvalue because I need the URL. The 3 column table I am querying is <date>,<true/false>,and last column is a <text with link>. Sorry I do not know how to put sample of the table, but I do not think the data is the issue. I use rich text value to get the link. But the issue is not there. If I run Logger.log on datex before I call getFDate, it is correct, it gives me only one value. But as soon as I call getFDate I get the double value.  "rowDate" seems to be the issue not "datex".