# How to make this sorting script run in all tabs except certain tabs (Sheets)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to sort specific columns on a google sheet but exluding a few different tabs. I use google scripts a decent amount in my job but most of the scripts I get from Stack and then edit them because I am not a developer/engineer, I'm in a non-tech role but I know a slight amount about coding.

Can someone that knows coding tell me what I am doing wrong?

I know there is a more efficient way to do the naming conventions of the columns and the ascending and I will change that later but wanted to see if anyone knows why I am getting this error? Thanks!

I found this code from a Stack post that I changed that I feel like should work but I keep getting this error on my trigger which is "onEdit":

"Error: The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet."

```
 function sortEverySheetTest() {
  var excludeSheetNames = ["Sheet 1","Sheet 2","Sheet 3", "Sheet 4", "Sheet 5", "Sheet 6", "Sheet 7", "Sheet 8"]; // <--- Added

  var sortFirst = 5;
  var sortFirstAsc = true;
  var sortSecond = 6;
  var sortSecondAsc = true;
   var sortThird = 7;
  var sortThirdAsc = true;
  var headerRows = 2;
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName();

  if (excludeSheetNames.includes(sheetName)) return; // <--- Added

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort([{ column: sortFirst, ascending: sortFirstAsc }, { column: sortSecond, ascending: sortSecondAsc }, { column: sortThird, ascending: sortThirdAsc }]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const excl = ["Sheet 1","Sheet 2","Sheet 3", "Sheet 4", "Sheet 5", "Sheet 6", "Sheet 7", "Sheet 8"]; 
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = e.source.getSheets().filter(sh => !~excl.indexOf(sh.getName())).map(sh => sh.getName());
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx) {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    let rg = sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow() - 2,sh.getLastColumn());
    rg.sort([{column:5,ascending:true},{column:6,ascending:true},{column:7,ascending:true}]);
  }
}
```

Here's the markdown table for my sheet data after sorting:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| 3 | 10 | 17 | 6 | 7 | 0 | 6 | 14 | 14 | 6 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | 33 | 19 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 0 | 19 | 14 |
| 5 | 3 | 18 | 16 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 9 | 5 | 16 | 19 |
| 6 | 16 | 0 | 12 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 13 | 19 | 17 | 12 |
| 7 | 14 | 2 | 19 | 4 | 6 | 14 | 2 | 16 | 12 | 8 |
| 8 | 10 | 5 | 5 | 13 | 10 | 3 | 8 | 2 | 15 | 15 |
| 9 | 14 | 5 | 16 | 9 | 10 | 13 | 0 | 17 | 16 | 7 |
| 10 | 4 | 9 | 8 | 4 | 10 | 13 | 10 | 17 | 19 | 0 |
| 11 | 0 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 11 | 0 | 15 | 4 | 14 | 19 |
| 12 | 17 | 12 | 2 | 9 | 12 | 4 | 13 | 5 | 11 | 17 |
| 13 | 14 | 4 | 0 | 5 | 14 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 17 | 2 |
| 14 | 5 | 5 | 18 | 19 | 14 | 9 | 0 | 5 | 9 | 2 |
| 15 | 15 | 5 | 13 | 15 | 16 | 2 | 7 | 1 | 14 | 19 |
| 16 | 10 | 15 | 18 | 17 | 16 | 13 | 16 | 13 | 10 | 11 |
| 17 | 9 | 12 | 1 | 3 | 17 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 9 |
| 18 | 12 | 5 | 16 | 10 | 17 | 5 | 1 | 8 | 14 | 9 |
| 19 | 16 | 2 | 99 | 2 | 17 | 8 | 11 | 2 | 2 | 14 |
| 20 | 19 | 13 | 16 | 13 | 17 | 16 | 11 | 10 | 14 | 15 |
| 21 | 2 | 18 | 9 | 10 | 18 | 3 | 16 | 1 | 17 | 19 |
| 22 | 2 | 7 | 12 | 6 | 18 | 9 | 3 | 6 | 13 | 18 |

Comment: Thanks for answering! Im getting the same error again though:

"Exception: The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.
    at onMyEdit(onmyedit:7:33)"

which is this line:

let rg = sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow() - 2,sh.getLastColumn());

And in my original code is this line: 

var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn());

Comment: Please provide a table of the sheet that will reproduce the error.

Comment: I made a small correction and tested it on some of my data and it works fine now.

Comment: Where is the table of data.  If you need help creating markdown tables look here [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)

Comment: Let me make a copy of the sheet but take out any sensitive data one minute!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11YSbqtItfepo3k17Ekh6H3q0wU1CrYcFdsyWjJtzVNo/copy

hopefully this link works.... I need the tabs with actual names to sort by those columns and then the tabs with sheet # not to sort (I took out some tabs so there is only up to Sheet 4)... I left the code in the google scripts

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow links to other spreadsheets

Comment: Ok no problem... the issue with the markdown table is that I have no problem getting a sorting script to work on one individual tab or every tab as a whole with getActiveSpreadsheet... the issue comes in when I try to make an exception for specific tabs... I even use the same range code: "var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn());" For all of these different scripts except for some reason the exception script says the range doesn't work

Comment: My problem is that if you can't provide a [mcve] then how can we be expected to provide solutions to a problem that we cannot reproduce.

Comment: I am SO sorry. I really appreciate your help... My original code actually works... for some reason it was giving an error on a copy of the original sheet I had for testing this new code but I made an entirely new sheet and it worked so I put it on my original sheet and it worked there too so I am so sorry for wasting your time.... if it's any consolation your code worked as well!