# Partial Match Not Working in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have this sheet tab that contains these columns:

[image]

In another tab, I have this column:

[image]

I want the result to be like this:

[image]

I have this formula that I'm using that somewhat works:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH($B2,Masterlist!$A$2:$A$139),Masterlist!$A$2:$A$139,"")),"where Col1 is not null")))
```

but the result I'm getting is like this:

[image]

Comment: Put some sample data in [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) so we dont' have to rewrite your screen shots. Also sort your data from longest length at top, to the bottom.

Comment: [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)

Comment: @pgSystemTester I was actually doing that earlier. But when I posted the question, it's not showing properly. Maybe because my internet connection here is weird. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [h1, ...vs1] = sh1.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  let obj1 = {};
  h1.forEach((h, i) => { obj1[h] = i + 1; });
  const code = sh1.getRange(2,obj1["Activity Code"],sh1.getLastRow() - 1).getDisplayValues().flat().map(c => c.replace(/ /g,''));
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const [h2, ...vs2] = sh2.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  let obj2 = {};
  h2.forEach((h, i) => { obj2[h] = i + 1; });
  const acct = sh2.getRange(2,obj2["Account"],sh2.getLastRow() - 1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  let arr = [["Activity Code","Account"]]
  acct.forEach((a,i) => 
    code.forEach(c => {
      if(~c.indexOf(a)) {
        arr.push([c,a]);
      }
    }
  ));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
  const sh3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  sh3.clearContents();
  sh3.getRange(1,1,arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

Sheet1:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Activity Code |
| 2 | _account1_immediate |
| 3 | _lunch_account2 |
| 4 | _break_account3_lunch |
| 5 | _break account 3 |

Sheet2:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Account |
| 2 | account1 |
| 3 | account2 |
| 4 | account3 |
| 5 | account11 |

Sheet3:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Activity Code | Account |
| 2 | _account1_immediate | account1 |
| 3 | _lunch_account2 | account2 |
| 4 | _break_account3_lunch | account3 |
| 5 | _breakaccount3 | account3 |

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will surely try this out. Though it's a bit weird. I deleted this question because it's failing to load earlier. And the expected message layout is not showing properly.