# Google Apps Script: Joining two or more columns with different column names

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I work with various groups at work. Each group tracks the same thing so I want to create a central tracker to gather better data for senior leadership. However, each group names the columns in their trackers something different and have the columns in a different order.

Is there a way in Google apps script where I can combine these same columns together?

An example: One group will call a column "project name" in A1 cell, then another would label the column "Initiative Name" in cell B1. But in a new sheet I want to combined them under 1 column name that I would label.

Thanks for any help!

I'm new to learning Google apps script so at this point I'm confused and lost.

Comment: Please provide a few tables of data sets that you wish to combine and explain how you wish to have them combined

Comment: Sure! Division 1, cell A1 column name is "project Name" under that title they have the project names as "project 1" in cell A2 and "project 2" in A3. Then in column B1 Division 1 has it titled as Start Date with the dates 1-1-2022 in column B2 and in column B3 is

Comment: Please post the data in your question as markup tables so that we can copy and paste them into a spreadsheet.  You may find it helpful to use the following create markdown tables [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)  Think about it do it carefully and provide us with and example of how you wish to combine them.

Comment: Sure! Division 1, cell A1 column name is "project Name" under that title they have the project names as "project 1" in cell A2 and "project 2" in cell A3. Then in column B1 Division 1 has it titled as Start Date with the dates 1-1-2022 in cell B2 and in cell B3 is 7-1-2022. Then Division 2 in Column A1 is titled Begin date and B1 is titled "initiative name". I'm looking to create a sheet that combines division 1 column project name with division 2 initiative name into 1 column so it reads down as project 1 project 2, initiative 1, initiative 2 with their corresponding dates

Comment: Again post the data as markdown tables in your question so that we can copy them and paste them into a spreadsheet.  Take your time do it carefully and think about it and provide us with an example of how you want the output to look like