# I'm trying to create Google Calendar Events from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a google calendar events from google sheets, but when I run my code, the dates are behind by 1 day and the time is behind by 1 hour. I don't know why that is happening, can you please help!

Here's my code:

```
function scheduleEvent() 
// Open the event calendar
{var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
var eventCal =             CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_9dd5324642f2f4c9e822f0cd8a3e4a20b5fac2e6965f73ca48cc07357094a35d@group.calendar.google.com" );

// Pull each event into code
var events = spreadsheet.getRange("A4:E13").getValues();

// Fill in event details by column
for (x=0; x<events.length; x)
{var col = events[x];

var eventName = col[0];
var startDate = col[1];
var endDate = col[2];
var loca = col[3];
var descr = col[4];

eventCal.createEvent(eventName, startDate, endDate, {location: loca, description: descr});
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a table of your data

Comment: [Creating a SO table using google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table/66772209#66772209)

Comment: You current loop can create a lot of events since the loop never terminates

Comment: please check the time zone of the script and of the spreadsheet, they must be the same and of course the same as yours.

Comment: @Cooper what is a loop? Sorry I am new to coding, never done this before. I also cant seem to share a screen shot of my data.

Comment: @Sergeinsas I tried that, still not working.

Comment: could you please share a copy of your Google sheet (without any personal data and in "read" mode) so I can try it myself with the same data structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function scheduleEvent() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("your cal id");
  var events = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  events.forEach((r, i) => {
    cal.createEvent(r[0], new Date(r[1]), new Date(r[2]), { location: r[3], description: r[4] });

  });
}
```

If you create too many events you might wish to try something like this to remove them.

```
function delevents() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("your cal id");
  var list = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  list.forEach((r, i) => {
    let evs = cal.getEvents(r[1],r[2]);
    if(evs && evs.length > 0) {
      evs.forEach(ev => {ev.deleteEvent()})
    }
  });
}
```

My Data Table:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Title | Start | End | Desc | Location |
| 2 | Event1 | 5/5/2023 12:00:00 | 5/5/2023 13:00:00 | Desc1 | Loc 1 |
| 3 | Event2 | 5/6/2023 13:00:00 | 5/6/2023 14:00:00 | Desc2 | Loca2 |

Comment: I tried this code and it didn't work, I got this error message: 

 
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.

Comment: It sounds like you inputs may be of the wrong type.  It works for me.

Comment: It may work now.