# Delete matching data using Google Sheets App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to write a Google App Script that would analyze data in column A, compare it to a specific range, f.e. B:E, and delete all cell values in that range, that appear in column A. Attaching photo for better visualization [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwKqy.png)

I however do not poses any coding knowledge, so that is a very hard task for me, eventhough it seems rather simple.

Could anyone help me out? I thank you in advance.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Ben | Diana | Donald | John |
| Amy | Jason | John | Elon | Robert |
| Hunter | Johan | Cena | John | Sam |
|  | Amy | Amy | Random | Hunter |

I tried using ChatGPT coding but that did not work really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  const as = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  const o = vs.map((r, i) => {
    let row = r.slice();
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (~as.indexOf(c)) {
        row[j] = "";
      }
    })
    return row;
  })
  rg.setValues(o)
}
```

Selected range is the active range.

It deletes all the selected cells that match a cell in column A

[image]

This is the output for your example:

|  | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ben | Diana | Donald |  |
| 2 | Jason |  | Elon | Robert |
| 3 | Johan | Cena |  | Sam |
| 4 |  | Random |  |  |

If you wish it to post the answer next to it to the right you can do it this way:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  const as = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  const o = vs.map((r, i) => {
    let row = r.slice();
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (~as.indexOf(c)) {
        row[j] = "";
      }
    })
    return row;
  })
  rg.offset(0, rg.getWidth() + 1).setValues(o)
}
```

And then it looks like this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ben | Diana | Donald | John |  |  | Diana | Donald | John |  |
| 2 | Amy | Jason | John | Elon | Robert |  | Jason | John | Elon | Robert |
| 3 | Hunter | Johan | Cena | John | Sam |  | Johan | Cena | John | Sam |
| 4 | Amy | Amy | Random | Hunter |  |  |  | Random |  |  |

Comment: Hello, thank you for your contribution. When I select the range and run the script, only this happens:

[link](https://pasteboard.co/MJEhjdRhAs7C.png)

Deletes data in column A which it shouldn't, and then a random cell deletion.

Comment: I had assume that you would not have selected column A

Comment: Still the same outcome if I select from column B forward, just column A doesn't get deleted

Comment: Yes that's what I thought you wanted

Comment: I reread your question I think that's the answer if not then you provide an example.

Comment: Yes, your example that you posted does exactly what I requested, but I get this:
[pre-script](https://pasteboard.co/PzmKz8j5SGlt.png)
[post-script](https://pasteboard.co/piPJKDNgzJyN.png)

Is it maybe because I use text and not numbers? If it's that, is there a way to tailor it for text and not numbers?

It doesn't

Comment: post your example data as a table so that I can copy it

Comment: My example was created with my code

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_CBMsNz57xi71IKodG51l7kLlja2HwGGQJcDtzljt3s/edit?usp=sharing

sorry for not being skillful enough, no clue how to post a table and make it look nice

Comment: Sorry but I do not follow links to spreadsheets please post data as a table

Comment: Here's some code to help create tables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table

Comment: ok I edited original post, I hope it's what you're looking for

Comment: I tried it on a different text set and on a number set - works. But when I use it on the table I posted, it doesnt. I have no clue but it was example only anyways, thank you ever so much