# How to get specific cell values from all sheets in a google spreadsheet and list the values in a new sheet using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the names of all my sheets and get specific cell values from each of it, and  list those values with its corresponding sheetname in another sheet which will be created upon running the appscript code.

I came up with this:

```
  var sheetID = "1tGjn4slbC2x7jtMDO7J6m-aWwvHWq2KJdtF4gT9kcEs"; 
  var allSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheets();

  //New Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet().setName('LEAVEBAL');

  for (var i = 0; i < allSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheetname = allSheets[i].getName();
    var sheettest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);

    Logger.log(sheetname);
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue(sheetname);

    var vals = sheettest.getRange(sheettest.getLastRow(),12, 1, 4).getValues();

      for (var j = 0; j < vals.length; j ++){
        Logger.log(vals[j]);
        
        sheet.getRange(j + 1, 2).setValues(vals[j]);
      }
```

Which results in an error. My question is, how can I get a result with a pattern like:

Sheet Name | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  A few comments, `getSheets()` returns an array of sheets so you don't need to `getSheetByName()`.  Second insert your sheet after you have looped through all the existing sheets otherwise you will get that one too.  Third use the Best Paractices of avoiding `getValue(s)/setValue(s)` in a loop.  Collect all of your new rows in an array say `results` and then one `setValues()`.

```
function myTest() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheets = spread.getSheets();

    let results = [];

    sheets.forEach( sheet => {
        let name = sheet.getName();
        console.log(name);
        let row = [name];
        let lastRow = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,4).getValues();
        console.log(lastRow);
        row = row.concat(lastRow[0]);
        results.push(row);
      }
    );

    sheet = spread.insertSheet('LEAVEBAL');
    sheet.getRange(1,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);

  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Spreadsheet.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [Sheet.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Sheet.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Spreadsheet.insertSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname)
- [Spreadsheet Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried changing

> sheet.getRange(j + 1, 2).setValues(vals[j]);

to

> sheet.appendRow([sheetname, vals[j][0], vals[j][1], vals[j][2], vals[j][3]]);

and removed

> sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue(sheetname);

and got the result I that want. If anyone has a better solution, feel free to comment. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using setValues to store the data is a little faster

```
function myfunk(sheetID = gobj.globals.test1id) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheets();
  var sh;
  try {
    sh = ss.insertSheet().setName('LEAVEBAL');
  }
  catch(e) {
    sh = ss.getSheetByName("LEAVEBAL")
  }
  sh.activate();
  sh.clearContents();
  let o = shts.map(s => {
    let name = s.getName()
    s.getRange("A1").setValue(name);
    let vs = s.getRange(s.getLastRow(),12,1,4).getValues().flat();
    vs.unshift(name);
    return vs;
  })
  o.unshift(["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5"]);
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o)
}
```

- [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table) - [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)