# Return Data from Google Sheet as table on HTML doc only if date in column D matches Today

Tags: html, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

## The Problem

I'm very new to working with APIs and google sheets in this way and this is my first time posting on stackflow. It was recommended by a friend. Thanks to other posts people have made, I was able to learn how to get data from a Google Sheet to post to an HTML doc as a table. However, its returning more than I want it to.

To be more specific, I have a Google spreadsheet that logs each time a student wants to use a building facility. It logs the name, location of facility, email, appointment time (start), appointment time (end), the slot ID (appointment ID#), and other things. I'm creating a search form that allows them to look up their slotID# (Column J) in the event that they can't access their emails - the backup plan is that it can be looked up from a terminal in class or the hallway. However, I don't change the google sheet each day, so data from previous days is still on the form. When a student types in their name, it returns every single time the student has ever used a facility. (See Image)

[The way the table currently returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgw10.png)

I only want it to return appointments made for the current date and ignore all other previous days and future days.

How would I code this so that when the table appears on the HTML doc, its only returning an array with data from the Google Sheet when Column D matches the current date which must be the same date the student is doing the search? In other words they can't look up Slot ID#s for past dates of past appointments made. Only the appointments made for the current date.

Here is my Demo [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jmnDyzf6nPVWgTtQHL8QqiewT5WZlf_oIIpCK63PrpI/edit#gid=0)

## Here is my code:

**code.gs
**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1jmnDyzf6nPVWgTtQHL8QqiewT5WZlf_oIIpCK63PrpI'; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRange        = 'Lobby!A2:J';                                   //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRange2       = '2nd Floor!A2:J';                                   //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRange3       = '3rd Floor!A2:J';                                   //** CHANGE !!!
  var dateRange             = 'Lobby!D2:D';                            //**Date variable attempt from sheet !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange).values;
  var data2 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange2).values;
  var data3 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange3).values;
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
    data2.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
    data3.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;

}
```

**index.html code
**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        <script>
          //PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 
             
          
          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }
        
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                             "<tr>"+                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                              "<th scope='col'>Name</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Location</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Email</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Time In</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Time Out</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Room #</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Student ID</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Comment 1</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Comment 2</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Slot ID</th>"+

                            "</tr>"+
                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              //div.empty()
              div.innerHTML = "Slot ID not found!";
            }
          }
        </script>
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ~ END ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                      <label for="searchtext">Search Text</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Type Your Name or ID #">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
                  </form>
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->
              
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
                <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
                  <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
                </div>
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**javascript.html code
**

```
<script>
    /*
  *THIS FUNCTION CALL THE getData() FUNCTION IN THE Code.gs FILE, 
  *AND PASS RETURNED DATA TO showData() FUNCTION
  */
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();

  //THIS FUNCTION GENERATE THE DATA TABLE FROM THE DATA ARRAY
  function showData(dataArray){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
        //CHANGE THE TABLE HEADINGS BELOW TO MATCH WITH YOUR SELECTED DATA RANGE
        columns: [
          {"title":"Name"},
          {"title":"Location"},
          {"title":"Email"},
          {"title":"Time In"},
          {"title":"Time Out"},
          {"title":"Room #"},
          {"title":"Student ID"},
          {"title":"Comment 1"},
          {"title":"Comment 2"},
          {"title":"Slot ID"},
        ]
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Please keep in mind that I'm very much a beginner, so make it as simple as you can for me. I hope I explained this well enough.

I tried adding date variables and a date function that was supposed to filter everything so it would only show if something in the array matched the current date. This failed miserably, I clearly didn't get this right. Probably wasn't even close.

```
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1jmnDyzf6nPVWgTtQHL8QqiewT5WZlf_oIIpCK63PrpI'; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRange        = 'Lobby!A2:J';                                   //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRange2       = '2nd Floor!A2:J';                                   //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRange3       = '3rd Floor!A2:J';                                   //** CHANGE !!!
  var dateRange             = 'Lobby!D2:D';                            //**Date variable attempt from sheet !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange).values;
  var data2 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange2).values;
  var data3 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange3).values;
  var dateSheet = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(SpreadsheetID, dateRange).values;
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
  document.write(today);
 
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext) && dateSheet == today) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
    data2.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
    data3.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;

}
```

**HERE IS MY SAMPLE TABLE:**

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Time In</th>
    <th>Time Out</th>
    <th>Room #</th>
    <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>Comment 1</th>
    <th>Comment 2</th>
    <th>Slot ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jay Spellz</td>
    <td>Lobby (Boys)</td>
    <td>Jpellz@example.com</td>
    <td>11/23/2023 9:10:00</td>
    <td>11/23/2023 9:15:00</td>
    <td>213</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>58167329</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Thomas Freeze</td>
    <td>Lobby (Boys)</td>
    <td>Freeze@example.com</td>
    <td>11/23/2023 9:15:00</td>
    <td>11/23/2023 9:20:00</td>
    <td>213</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>58167330</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ken Hag</td>
    <td>Lobby (Boys)</td>
    <td>Kdogg@example.com</td>
    <td>11/23/2023 9:20:00</td>
    <td>11/23/2023 9:25:00</td>
    <td>213</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>58167340</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jay Spellz</td>
    <td>Lobby (Boys)</td>
    <td>Jpellz@example.com</td>
    <td>12/23/2023 9:40:00</td>
    <td>12/23/2023 9:45:00</td>
    <td>213</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>58207915</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ken Hag</td>
    <td>Lobby (Boys)</td>
    <td>Kdogg@example.com</td>
    <td>12/23/2023 9:40:00</td>
    <td>12/23/2023 9:45:00</td>
    <td>213</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>58207920</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Terry Shark</td>
    <td>Lobby (Boys)</td>
    <td>Slittleshark@example.com</td>
    <td>12/23/2023 11:40:00</td>
    <td>12/23/2023 11:45:00</td>
    <td>213</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>58207000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just filtered column D of the output to be equal to today's date

```
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1jmnDyzf6nPVWgTtQHL8QqiewT5WZlf_oIIpCK63PrpI'; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRange        = 'Lobby!A2:J';                                   //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRange2       = '2nd Floor!A2:J';                                   //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRange3       = '3rd Floor!A2:J';                                   //** CHANGE !!!
  var dateRange             = 'Lobby!D2:D';                            //**Date variable attempt from sheet !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange).values;
  var data2 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange2).values;
  var data3 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange3).values;
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
    data2.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
    data3.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  let dt = new Date();
  let dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  let far = ar.filter(r => {
    let d = new Date(r[3]);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf()
    return dtv == dv;
  } ).filter(e => e);
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(far))
  return far;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. It wouldn't produce any results even when I purposely put in today's date to a row in column D.

I copied and pasted the code exactly as you had  it. I'm not sure why it didn't work. Perhaps because its not comparing or pulling any dates from column D?  Also, in order to test it (since no other data was put in today) how would I set for a previous date? Like 11/23/2023 for example.

Comment: I found an error in the code it should work now.

Comment: How do I post a table? Each time i try to paste one in the comments here, it doesn't format like a table. I'm sorry, I am new to this. 

I'm going to repost above in my initial question under "Sample Table"

Comment: I found the error and corrected it.  I don't need the data any  longer

Comment: - [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks so much. If I need to change the date for testing purposes, how do I do that? Right now its set to do the current date and time, but what do I change to make it work with other dates if I ever want to do that.

Comment: Part of the reason why the code wasn't working at first was because of how I formatted the dates. The date and time were in the google sheet cell, but they were formatted to show only time. When I changed the format to show date and time, everything started working. I was able to change some dates around to produce results. In the future if I wanted to test it out using a specific past date how would I change that?

Comment: Right now its Sunday (where I'm at) so there were no reservations logged allowing me to test, I had to type in dummy data. I'd like to be able to test it with a previous date because I'm trying to avoid adding dummy data -- the school wants to use this spreadsheet and it would look bad if I forgot to delete the dummy data or missed an item.

Comment: Would this work: 
  let dt = new Date();
  let dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(11),dt.getDate(23).valueOf();
  let far = ar.filter(r => {
    let d = new Date(r[3]);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(11),d.getDate(23)).valueOf()
    return dtv == dv;

Lets say if I wanted to set the date to 11/23/2023?

Comment: No. The month would have to be 10.  In the Date() object months run from 0 to 11

Comment: - [Date.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Comment: the values aren't working. I put the code as follows: 

let dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(2023),dt.getMonth(10),dt.getDate(23)).valueOf();
  let far = ar.filter(r => {
    let d = new Date(r[3]);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(2023),d.getMonth(10),d.getDate(23)).valueOf()

That was all I changed and it didn't work. Is there another way to put it in?

Comment: I think all you have to do is change this line from: `let dt = new Date();` to this `let dt = new Date(2023,10,23);` - [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Comment: Thanks so much, that fixed everything I needed.