# Combine 3 google sheet macros

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I tired to create one macro that would

1)Freeze row 1 
2)Remove use Len to shorten a string for entire column

3)Copy the shortened string and paste it over top of itself using values instead of the formula

4)Convert that same column to number

5)Sort sheet by that same column

6)delete the column now that the sheet is sorted and unfreeze the 1st row.

I have it in 3 macros but can't get it to work in one.

I would like to have macro 1 call 2 and 3 or get them all into one if possible.
thank you.

```
function _1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('1:1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setFrozenRows(1);
  spreadsheet.getRange('J2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=right(h2,len(H2)-4)');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('J2:J31'), 
  SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);<br>
};

function _2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J:J').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J:J').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0.00');

};

function _3() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J:J').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().sort(10, true);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have a table of data before and after each function.  Most of us do not write our code like this and I don't even like to read this kind of code.  But I'd be more likely to assist you with a starting table of data and a table for each step as you would like it to occur. - [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)