# google sheets app script finding matches between two 2-d arrays with out 4 nested for loops

Tags: google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I have two 2 dimensional arrays.

First array holds a list of ID's selected:

```
 ids_list =     [[2,  3], [3, 5]]
```

The second holds the ID and the name :

```
control_mapping =  [[1, "name-1"], [2, "name-2"], [3, "name-3"], [4, "name-4"], [5, "name-5"], [6, "name-6"]]
```

What I'm trying to do is build a concatenated string with the names of all the ID's chosen

So the desired result would be `["name-2\n name-2", "name-3\n name-5"]`

I know I can do 4 nested for loops, but I'm hoping there is something more efficient than that. App script seems to have lots of tricks, but this ole c programmer doesn't know them yet.

Thanks much!

Edit, adding table info

Id's come from sheet 'Threats', column K
[image]

Controls come from sheet 'Controls', Column A and B

[image]

The goal is the write out 'Controls' the concatenated names of the controls selected. This write out part I know how to do, getting the output array with the concatenated names is my problem.

So the end goal is to have the code create the output:
[image]

Comment: Please put your array in to a markdown table and provide headers with what the columns are. - [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)

Comment: Images are not quite as useful to us since we can't just copy the data like in a markdown table.  Follow the link above to find an easy way to create markdown tables.

Comment: `["name-2\n name-2", "name-3\n name-5"]` should be `["name-2\n name-3", "name-3\n name-5"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over the array with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to create an actual map object:

```js
const ids_list = [
  [2, 3],
  [3, 5],
];
const control_mapping = [
  [1, 'name-1'],
  [2, 'name-2'],
  [3, 'name-3'],
  [4, 'name-4'],
  [5, 'name-5'],
  [6, 'name-6'],
];

const control_mapping_map = new Map(control_mapping);
const out = ids_list.map((row) =>
  row.map((key) => control_mapping_map.get(key)).join('\n ')
);
console.log(out);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks!! its so sleek and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Finding matches between two arrays

```
function myfunk00() {
  const a1 = [[2, 3], [3, 5]];
  const a2 = [[1, "name-1"], [2, "name-2"], [3, "name-3"], [4, "name-4"], [5, "name-5"], [6, "name-6"]];
  const idA = a2.map(r => r[0]);
  const sNames = a1.reduce((acc,r,i) => {
    let idx = idA.indexOf(r[0]);
    if(~idx) {
      acc.push([i,a2[idx][0],a2[idx][1]]);
    }
    return acc;
  },[["a1-index","a2-col1","a2-col2"]]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(sNames));
}
```

Output  Displayed on Sheet:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1-index | a2-col1 | a2-col2 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | name-2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | name-3 |

a1:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |

a2:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | name-1 |
| 2 | 2 | name-2 |
| 3 | 3 | name-3 |
| 4 | 4 | name-4 |
| 5 | 5 | name-5 |
| 6 | 6 | name-6 |

Comment: Hey copper, I'm struggling to understand the output. I'm not seeing where 'name-2\n name-3' is printing , for say the first result.

Comment: First column is the index into a1. Second and third columns are the corresponding match data from a2.  First line is headers second line is first match, third line is second match