# Script Google Apps: Filter by dates from today

Tags: date, google-apps-script, filter

From this kind of table:

| Dates | Objects |
| --- | --- |
| 23/02/2024 | Object A |
| 23/02/2024 | Object A |
| 24/02/2024 | Object B |
| 24/02/2024 | Object C |
| 15/03/2024 | Object C |
| 15/03/2024 | Object B |
| 17/03/2024 | Object A |

I would like to filter only objects that occours from today to the next 3 days.
Everytime I'd run this script I would like to filter from "today" to next 3 days.

So, I can focus only on objects that matters today, tomorrow, and so on.

Could you help me?
Thank you!

I'm noobie on scripts. I just read some past articles, but I could not find anything similar

Comment: - [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)   
- [How to make a data table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/206484)

Answer (score 0):

Filter by Dates: You supply the date column.

```
function filterDates() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtl = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();//low
  const dth = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate() + 3).valueOf();//hi
  const col =2;//column of dates to filter
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r => {
    let d = new Date(r[col - 1]).valueOf();
    return d >= dtl && d <= dth;
  }).filter(e => e);
  return vs;
}
```