# Google Apps Script-find last data at target sheet and then append remaining data from source sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

After a lot of search I found below piece of code which works but it overwrites wholly in target data rather than appending.So,how can I find the last entered data in target sheet say B column and after that it appends data from there onward -

```
function copy() {
  var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetkey");
  var targetSheet = targetSS.getSheetByName("SheetAB1");

  var ranges = ["A5:H1100", "J5:M1100", "U5:X1100"];
  ranges.forEach(range => {
    var data = sourceSheet.getRange(range).getValues();
    targetSheet.getRange(range).setValues(data);
  })
}
```

I want to add a line of codes that it will find last entered data in target sheet which will match from the source sheet and then paste the data at target sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function copy() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.ssid);
  const tsh = tss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, , j, k, l, m, , , , , , , , u, v, x] = ssh.getRange(ssh.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 24).getValues().flat();
  const dlr = tsh.getLastRow();
  tsh.getRange(dlr + 1, 1, 1, 8).setValues([[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]]);
  tsh.getRange(dlr + 1, 10, 1, 4).setValues([[j, k, l, m]]);
  tsh.getRange(dlr + 1, 21, 1, 3).setValues([[u, v, x]]);
}
```

Comment: Hi,I have tried this but the problem is that it is again copying the whole data.Let me explain.A user is given a task in which in a sheet he goes on entering the data suppose till A5 and across.Now  at the end of the each day I will run script in destination sheet,it must copies the value .Now the user again goes on entering the data from A6 and so on.Again at the end of the day I will run the script at destination sheet then it must copy the data from A6 and not whole data again as it would be duplicate.I hope u understand.Only the incremental data is to be appended by running script.

Comment: Please include the additional description and explanation in the post of your question.  If you could provide some samples of editing situations and how the code is to respond.  I understand it a little better I think.  However, I need a little more.  Sorry but I need a little more info.

Comment: Ok I have shared a folder with two files in it  source & target.I hope with files it would be easy.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cQxOrEUiaA6-Ct2PVKNlSgWJPC45_ROV

Comment: I'm not familiar with that link so I'm not going to follow it.  If you wish my help you must post whatever information you wish to provide within the context of your question.  Otherwise I cannot assist you any further.

Comment: Let me know how can I post sample demo file.

Comment: What kind of file is it?

Comment: It's a Google spreadsheet

Comment: I use markdown tables - [creating markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772208/a-script-to-simplify-creating-a-so-table)     to provide easy access to data and gif images for demos.